Compute count(*) of unique occurrences into new column without group by in a single select query
Is is possible in SQL Server to do something similar to this simplified example with one select? While googling it myself, I came across a question on SO with very similar requirement, but, unfortunately, it's not related to SQL Server.
declare @t1 table (id int, name varchar(60))
declare @t2 table (id int, name varchar(60))
declare @t3 table (id int, name varchar(60))
declare @t4 table (t1id int, t2id int, t3id int, id int, name varchar(60))

insert into @t1 values 
    (1, 't1_1'),
    (2, 't1_2')
insert into @t2 values
    (1, 't2_1'),
    (2, 't2_2'),
    (3, 't2_3')
insert into @t3 values
    (1, 't3_1'),
    (2, 't3_2'),
    (3, 't3_3'),
    (4, 't3_4')
insert into @t4 values
    (2, 1, 4, 1, 't4_1'),
    (3, 2, 1, 2, 't4_2'),
    (1, 1, 1, 3, 't4_3'),
    (2, 2, 2, 4, 't4_4'),
    (3, 3, 3, 5, 't4_5'),
    (1, 2, 3, 6, 't4_6'),
    (1, 3, 1, 7, 't4_7'),
    (1, 2, 1, 8, 't4_8'),
    (1, 2, 4, 9, 't4_9'),
    (2, 2, 3, 10, 't4_10')

select base.*,
( -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-specifying-multiple-values-as-a-derived-table-in-a-from-clause
    select count(distinct v.name3)
    from
    (
        values (base.name1, base.name2, base.name3)
    ) as v (name1, name2, name3)
    group by v.name1, v.name2
) as [ShowCountOfName3PerName1&Name2OnEveryRow]
from
(
    select t1.name as name1,
    t2.name as name2,
    t3.name as name3,
    t4.name as name4
    from @t4 as t4
    inner join @t1 as t1
    on t4.t1id = t1.id
    inner join @t2 as t2
    on t4.t2id = t2.id
    inner join @t3 as t3
    on t4.t3id = t3.id
) as base
order by base.name1, base.name2, base.name3, base.name4

Unfortunately, this query displays only the digit 1 on every row, while this is the desired result:



name1
name2
name3
name4
ShowCountOfName3PerName1&Name2OnEveryRow




t1_1
t2_1
t3_1
t4_3
1


t1_1
t2_2
t3_1
t4_8
3


t1_1
t2_2
t3_3
t4_6
3


t1_1
t2_2
t3_4
t4_9
3


t1_1
t2_3
t3_1
t4_7
1


t1_2
t2_1
t3_4
t4_1
1


t1_2
t2_2
t3_2
t4_4
2


t1_2
t2_2
t3_3
t4_10
2



I tried it this way:
select base.*,
cnt.[ShowCountOfName3PerName1&Name2OnEveryRow]
from
(
    select t1.name as name1,
    t2.name as name2,
    t3.name as name3,
    t4.name as name4
    from @t4 as t4
    inner join @t1 as t1
    on t4.t1id = t1.id
    inner join @t2 as t2
    on t4.t2id = t2.id
    inner join @t3 as t3
    on t4.t3id = t3.id
) as base
outer apply
(
    select base.name1, base.name2,
    count(distinct base.name3) as [ShowCountOfName3PerName1&Name2OnEveryRow]
    from base
    group by base.name1, base.name2
) as cnt
where base.name1 = cnt.name1
and base.name2 = cnt.name2
order by base.name1, base.name2, base.name3, base.name4

The result is Invalid object name 'base'.
I can imagine this as a stored procedure where I insert the result into declare @result table(...) and then update @result set..., but this way it will have to be a stored procedure and to enumerate a result set of over 100k rows and update all of them every time. While I need this to be a view to be able to query it with Entity Framework in a more efficient way. Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

OK I will edit it. I do apologize!

I think what you want is a windowed count check out the docs for over (partition by)

The GROUP BY is your subquery isn't needed either; it serves no purpose or could cause an error.

You've shown us your non-working result, but you need to show us the results you wish to achieve.

@Dale K, your are correct. I just edited the question to show what I need to get as a result from the query.

Your mistake is using APPLY join in both cases. It will only take values for the current row, thus you will always get 1.
Solution 1: Use a window function
There is a catch: COUNT( DISTINCT x ) OVER is not supported in SQL Server.
Use can use DENSE_RANK() workaround instead:
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY t1id, t2id ORDER BY t3id ASC ) + DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY t1id, t2id ORDER BY t3id DESC ) - 1
FROM @T4

Credit to JoeFletch
Solution 2: Use a plain simple INNER JOIN
SELECT Src.*, Cnt.Cnt
FROM @T4 AS Src
    INNER JOIN(
            SELECT t1id, t2id, COUNT( DISTINCT t3id ) AS Cnt
            FROM @T4
            GROUP BY t1id, t2id
        ) AS Cnt 
        ON Src.t1id = Cnt.t1id AND Src.t2id = Cnt.t2id

P.S. for brevity I did not include joins to t1, t2, t3 tables
